# Deleting selected row from datagridview and database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am writing this code for deleting selected row from datagridview and database at a time.
but i got the error in  "deleteButton.Click"

```
deleteButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DeleteRecord);

 private DeleteRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.SelectedRows)
 {
  int rowIdToDelete = row.Cells[ID].Value;
  using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string query = "DELETE FROM [Record] WHERE ID = " + rowIdToDelete;
                    conn.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                        {
                            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                            adapter.Update(ds);
                            dataGridView.DataSource = ds;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
 }

}
```

Comment: What is the error? Why define a new datatable and fill it again. You are supposed to delete a row?

Comment: int rowIdToDelete =(int)row.Cells['ID'].Value; and then you have to  execte the querry not fill the table agin

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `rowIdToDelete` within quotes.

```
string query = "DELETE FROM [Record] WHERE ID = " + "'rowIdToDelete'";
```

Also if `ID` is column name with add double quotes,

```
int rowIdToDelete = row.Cells["ID"].Value;
```

Comment: private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
     {
         dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
     }
 }